# Spring web flow and ExtJs 4

Tags: extjs, spring-webflow

I am not able to find a concrete answer yet on this forum or other's that, whether spring web flow can be used with Extjs 4.2 or later release of Extjs.
In case some one has integrated then kindly let me know the basic steps or guide to a specific example will be really helpful.

Thanks in Advance.
Rohit Dwivedi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: "Yes".

Yes, because ExtJS does not need to (and does not) know how the server side is implemented. In its very essence, Ext sends a request to the server and expect a response, usually containing pertinent data.

In real life, you need to make decisions what part of the application logic will run on the server and what on the client and what the interface (API, request/response) will be between the two.

From the Spring site:

> `Spring Web Flow`: Supports building web applications with controlled navigation such as checking in for a flight or applying for a loan.

So, if you want/need the server to be responsible for such flows, then go ahead.

If you want to implement the application logic (flows) at Ext client, then continue looking for the server side language/platform as you do not need the `Web Flow` functionality.

Comment: Thanks Saki for providing the crux of solution.
I am pretty new to both the technologies so get this doubt.
Will explore in detail, the approaches suggested by you.